# How can i redirect https requests to my own server in node js

Tags: node.js, windows, https, proxy

Let's say I have a C# app that sends **HTTPS** requests to a webserver.

`https://www.webserver.com/checkid=anything`

And the web server checks the Id of the request and returns a string response such as `Not Active` back to the app.

This response will lock some features inside the app.

Is there any way I can redirect that request to another server that I controll and send fake responses such as `Active` back to my client app through node js proxy or something?

**Note:** I dont have access to the app source.

Comment: You could create a host entry in your hosts file, such as `example.com 127.0.0.1`, example.com is now your localhost and you can start a webserver there and do with the request what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found another better solution, I just used **[Fiddler Everywhere](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/mock-server-response)** to change the server response to a custom one.